# make custom xml shape android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable, shapes

I need to make custom shape like below:
[image: design image]

in order to do that I've wrote below xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    >
    <item android:id="@+id/ring1">
        <shape
            android:innerRadiusRatio=""
            android:shape="ring"
            android:tint="@color/white"
            android:useLevel="false"></shape>

    </item>

    <item>
        <shape
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:innerRadius="0dp"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thickness="140dp"
            android:useLevel="false">
            <gradient
                android:centerColor="#00F913"
                android:endColor="#006A10"
                android:startColor="#006A10" />

        </shape>

    </item>
    

</layer-list>
```

which it's result is:

[image: result image]

**And there is 3 problems:**

1. 1st: when I give it to any views background the outer white line
   wouldn't appear
2. 2nd: the shape is not a ring when i give it to views background
3. 3rd: the original view has a color at center and it has other color
   around but with gradient I can add color to start, center, end and
   in the middle the middle gradient is extends to borders

Answer (score 1):

> 1st: when I give it to any views background the outer white line wouldn't appear

You can use `oval` shape instead of using `ring` for the white part., and add padding as much you need the radius of the outer white part as modified below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/white" />
            <padding
                android:bottom="7dp"
                android:left="7dp"
                android:right="7dp"
                android:top="7dp" />
        </shape>

    </item>

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <size
                android:width="36dp"
                android:height="36dp" />
            <gradient
                android:centerColor="#00F913"
                android:endColor="#006A10"
                android:startColor="#006A10" />
        </shape>

    </item>

</layer-list>
```

> 2nd: the shape is not a ring when i give it to views background

You can use [`ShapeableImageView`](https://gist.github.com/gabrielemariotti/446c63ea2aed81aafc0bdec1488e27c9)

**First:** add below dependency in gradle module level

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha04'
```

**Second:** create below style in style.xml

```
<style name="circled">
    <item name="cornerSize">50%</item>
</style>
```

**Third:** apply the style to a  `ShapeableImageView` using `app:shapeAppearanceOverlay` attribute

> 3rd: the original view has a color at center and it has other color around but with gradient I can add color to start, center, end and in the middle the middle gradient is extends to borders

This should be solved by using  `ShapeableImageView`, please check below result after running the app

[image]

Sample test

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/circled"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/some_circle" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```